# How can I set environment variable for another user account in Windows?

Tags: windows, environment-variables, ms-dos

My scheduled task exe runs under a domain account. I need to set an environment variable for that account but logging in as me.

I did StackOverFlow some answers where they suggest editing the registry for the SID of that account but I couldn't find that SID in the HKEY_USERS.

I tried using SETX but was not sure of the /s parameter, as the docs suggest "Remote Computer". Is there any way I can log in as me to that remote computer where the scheduled job runs and set an environment variable for that service account?

Thanks!

Comment: setx won't help you at all, setx first of all is a bit of a hazard if setting the path or a variable that alraedy has a name 'cos do it wrong and you lose the whole variable contents.  Also setx just has the option to set either a user environment variable or a system environment variable. It may be that you need to set a system environment variaable. That can be done either manually or with setx or  without setx.. Using the reg command

Comment: If you are to use setx, then you'd want the /M for system-wide. But you can use the reg command too  https://superuser.com/questions/647505/set-enviroment-variable-setx

Comment: Does it have to be a user environment variable?  Is a system environment variable an option instead?

Comment: Thanks for your response @barlop. I have to set a user environment variable specifically and ONLY. I tried the setx command from my machine giving the IP address of the remote server where the  scheduled job runs (on the /s parameter) and indicated the service domain account for the /u parameter. It did say "Saved Successfully".  But when I log into that remote server, that env variable is still added to "my" account. The /u went for a toss I guess.  If I do have to use the reg command, can you please let me know what the command is to set to another user?

Comment: Well if you have to do it as another user specifically and not system, then you can probably RunAs a cmd as that user

Comment: Looks I responded a minute too early!  That's a terrific idea to do RunAs. Let me try it out!  Thanks!

Comment: @HillCountry yeah just to be claer this is the kind of thing i'm talking about  `C:\WINDOWS>runas /user:blah123 c:\windows\system32\cmd.exe` (if the username was blah123). And BTW, if wanting to run a command on a remote computer, sysinternals have a command called psexec  for that.

Comment: Yep. RunAs worked great. :-). I did do a SET by logging in again as that user and was able to see it. Thanks a lot again! How can I mark this as the Answer?  This site is completely new to me.

Comment: @HillCountry The set command won't be permanent,.. To make it permanent you'd have to either do it manually in the GUI ,or use setx or the reg command

Comment: @HillCountry i've just posted an answer so you can accept that if you want, thanks

Comment: @barlop. I just wanted to see all the env variables for that user. That's why I just fired SET to verify the just add variable, as it lists out everything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could set a system-wide environment variable rather than a user one.

Or you could set a user one, but by first doing runas cmd as that user, i.e. `C:\Windows>runas /user:blah123 c:\windows\system32\cmd.exe`   You could use the reg command  or setx command from there.
[Set enviroment variable setx](https://superuser.com/questions/647505/set-enviroment-variable-setx)

Note- There is a "reg command". One editor tried to edit this answer and the edit got approved, where they changed "reg command" to registry. That would be wrong. The reg command is the reg command.

Comment: Thanks! Marked it as the answer!